# github connection timed out on a mac

Tags: git, github, connection, vpn

```
git pull origin master
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I keep getting the following error when trying to pull from github, I haven't tried a push but I assume the same occurs.  How do I update my connection on a mac, to allow for push/pull with a github repo?

Comment: if this was happening about 20 minutes ago, github was having some trouble. it should be back to normal now. can you try again to make sure the error persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was actually a remote problem on Github's end. As their status site points out, they had slight issues with their load balancers, causing connections to time out for a few minutes.
As the asker confirmed in the comments, everything is working fine now.